# Python returns nothing after recursive call

Tags: python, recursion, return-value

I am working on a python script that calculates an individual's tax based on their income.

The system of taxation requires that people are taxed based on how rich they are or how much they earn.

The first **1000** is not taxed,
The next **9000**  is taxed 10%
The next **10200** is taxed 15% 
The next **10550** is taxed 20%
The next **19250** is taxed 25%
Anything left after the above is taxed at 30%

I have the code running and working and I am able to get the code working to follow the conditions above using recursion.

However, I have a problem returning the total_tax for the which should be the return value of the function.

For example, an income of **20500** should be taxed **2490.0**.

Here is my code snippet below:

```
def get_tax(income, current_level=0, total_tax=0,):
    level = [0, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3]
    amount = [1000, 9000, 10200, 10550, 19250, income]

    if income > 0 and current_level <=5:
        if income < amount[current_level]:
            this_tax = ( income * level[current_level] )
            income -= income

        else:    
            this_tax = ( level[current_level] * amount[current_level] )
            income -= amount[current_level]
            current_level += 1

        total_tax += this_tax
        print total_tax    
        get_tax(income, current_level, total_tax)

    else:
        final =  total_tax
        return final

get_tax(20500)
```

As you can see from the snippet, it does not work when I put the return statement in an else block, I have also tried doing it without the else block but it still does not work.

Here is a link to the snippet on [Repl.it](https://repl.it/D8si/1)

Comment: I have tried `return get_tax(income, current_level, total_tax)` and that does not solve the problem.

Comment: You don't increment current level in the second if.  Sprinkle in a few prints or step through in a debugger!

Comment: `.3` is `30%`, not `.3%`

Comment: @tdelaney

Are you sure you went through the snippet? The algorithm is correct and I have been able to solve the problem with erip's help.

Comment: @njzk2 

Thanks, the correction has been made.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The was not returning because the return statement was missing from the recursive call. Adding the return fixes it.

```
def get_tax(income, current_level=0, total_tax=0,):
    level = [0, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3]
    amount = [1000, 9000, 10200, 10550, 19250, income]
    
    if income > 0 and current_level <=5:
        if income < amount[current_level]:
            this_tax = ( income * level[current_level] )
            income -= income
            
        else:    
            this_tax = ( level[current_level] * amount[current_level] )
            income -= amount[current_level]
            current_level += 1
        
        total_tax += this_tax
        return get_tax(income, current_level, total_tax)
    
    else:
        final =  total_tax
        return final
print(get_tax(20500))
```

Answer (score 4):

It's returning nothing because you're not `return`ing.

`return get_tax(income, current_level, total_tax)`.

Now that it's returning something, you need to do something with the returned value.

Comment: I have tried that and it still doesn't work.
I would appreciate it if you can modify the code and save a revision of it on Repl.it.

Comment: @OlawaleAkinseye `print(get_tax(20500))`

Comment: It returns the right values but I am unable to return `total_tax` and `print(get_tax(20500))` did not work.

Comment: I officially don't understand your question. You say `20500` should return `2490.0`, which it does.

Comment: Those are just printed values while the function is still executing, not the return value.